# iOS development: access to device usage data

Tags: ios, iphone

If I develop an iOS app, can it have the ability to access usage information of the user’s device?

I want to monitor and display how many hours of the day the user uses their phone. For example: today, you spend 6 hours using your phone.

Thanks.

Comment: [Apple will introduce that feature in iOS 12](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/06/ios-12-introduces-new-features-to-reduce-interruptions-and-manage-screen-time/)

Comment: Do you know if developers will be able to access the data?